# Why do I get a 'Failed to set value' error when trying to add a 'Copy Location' constraint to my rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints, error

I'm trying add a Copy Location constraint but it doesn't work. I am making a metarig like in the video but if I press enter its cast nothing happens.

I tried picker thing I get this error:

[image]

[image]

Blend file link: https://dosya.co/9qudtsa52r77/1.blend.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you use Bone Constraint between bones, you need go to Pose Mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this constraint between bones, try to use bone constraint in pose mode.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.  It'd be great if you could include a picture of where you go in blender to do this and maybe a quick shot of the results.

Comment: I use bone constraints in "Pose Mode". You can see Bone Constraint Properties in Object Mode and Pose Mode under Bone Properties.
https://sun9-56.userapi.com/impf/JPFlbEZIFnBRq4jZ4xMiR340A0kp2uITAVYsAw/ugDAm3Nrxvw.jpg?size=954x1268&quality=96&sign=5082cc27f3155f9c1dd59ba890dfc014&type=album

Comment: You can use the edit link at the bottom of your answer to include more detail.  Comments aren't indexed in Google, and I think this is worth some points